# Is ZSH completion system capable of completing multiple arguments at the same time?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion, zsh-zle

**Scenario:**

Let's say a script `my_online_searcher <query>` opens a browser with the search for `query`, where `query` can be multiple words long. This same script also provides a utility flag `-s <query>` that shows the search engine's suggestions. E.g.:

```
$ my_online_searcher -s lion rema
lion remake
lion remake cast
lion remake zoo tycoon 2
lion remake zt2
remake lion king
remastered lion's share
remake lion king 2019
remastered lion king
remake lion king trailer
remaking lion king
```

**Desired outcome:**

The user would type `$ my_online_searcher lion rema[TAB]` and ZSH completion menu would give the above options.

**Attempts to achieve desired outcome:**

Create a little completions script `_my_online_searcher` that pretty much calls the `my_online_search -s <query>` support function to give out options. Something like:

```
[...]
completions=(${(f)"$(my_online_searcher -s ${arg} ${words:2})"})
_describe 'suggestions' completions
[...]
```

This allows for the spaces to be escaped and allow ZSH to see the `query` as a single argument.

However, a per-word completion does not allow the progressive completion of the suggestions. Either it repeats the previous words, or filters out suggestions that do not begin with the first arguments (e.g. `$ my_online searcher lion rema[TAB]` -> `$ my_online_searcher lion remake lion king`).

One idea was to modify the `LBUFFER` inside the completion script. This turned out to not be allowed as ZSH gives the error that `LBUFFER` is readonly

**TL;DR:**

Is it possible to have ZSH completion system see all the arguments after the command as a modifiable argument? In other words, can I propose completions to multiple arguments at the same time in ZSH?